# window is not defined in react server side rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

I am using server side rendering and while bundling the server file via webpack i am getting an error.

### ReferenceError: window is not defined

I even tried faking a window object but it didn't work either.

I did this with no success

```
if (typeof window === "undefined") {
  global.window = {};
}
```

I also made sure i am only using window object inside componentDidMount.

Can anyone please help me out? Why i am getting this and how can i resolve it?

Comment: did you tried with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38951721/react-js-server-side-issue-window-not-found

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS yes, but it didn't work.

Comment: Pretty sure you want `===` or `==` instead of `!==`, since you are trying to set the global var if it is **is** undefined.

Comment: @JoshuaT hey thanx for letting me know. It was a typo and i have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
if (process.browser) {
  // client-side-only code will make sure that your code runs inside the browser
}
```

Comment: Hey, @scott-agirs thanx for the response. But this is should do where and what should be inside the if? can you please elaborate?