# Javascript library taking too long time to respond

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am working with Node and React(NextJS) SSR based project, I have added [createjs](https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/createjs.min.js) because I have javascript based animations, unfortunately it dosen't have NPM package so I download the minified js library and serving from local server, but after adding this library to HEAD after 20-30 seconds it gives response, when I tried this on plain HTML it takes just 20-30 miliseconds only to renponce. What should I do to minimize response time

```
componentDidMount(){

 this.checkLib()
}

checkLib(){

setTimeout(()=>{
   if(window.createjs){
    console.log('library is ready')
   }else{
    this.checkLib()
   }
},500)

}  


render(){
return(
   <Head>
          {(typeof window !='undefined')
          ? <script src='./../static/js/createjs.min.js' />
          :'' }
   <Head>
)
}
```

Comment: why don't you include it as a module in your code?

Comment: It have window object. so it throws error on server because window object not found on serverside

Comment: so are you doing server side rendering too?

Comment: @DanielA.White yes I have mention on my question too, It's Nextjs based SSR project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38951721/react-js-server-side-issue-window-not-found

Answer (score 0):

I add `global npm` package it returns window and document object. It returns window object on DidMount event and It helps me to add library on initial level.